# How to clear screen in `Xamarin.UITest.IApp.Repl()` terminal on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, testing, terminal, xamarin.uitest

I would like have a command similar to `clear` in git bash terminal.
After some search I tried already `clear`, `cls`, `reset`, `:reset`, `C-i`, `C-I`, `C-l`, but non of it works.

Comment: How you tried printing: "\033[2J\033[1;1H" or "\033c" or '\x1bc'

Comment: Didn't help neither. By the way, did you mean "type" by saying "print"?